# Как правильно оформить цитату? 3

Tags: цитата

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно оформить следующую цитату:

Как писал А. Пушкин, «и пальцы просятся к перу, перо к бумаге. Минута – и стихи свободно потекут».

Смущает то, что эта цитата как будто встроена в предложение на правах его компонента, но сама представляет собой полтора предложения... Как поступать в таких случаях? Нужно ли ставить многоточие ("...и пальцы просятся к перу..."), или, может быть, можно оформить с двоеточием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Варианты оформления:**

(1) Как писал А. Пушкин, «...и пальцы просятся к перу, перо к бумаге. Минута – и стихи свободно потекут».

(2) А. Пушкин писал:  «...и пальцы просятся к перу, перо к бумаге. Минута – и стихи свободно потекут».

Выбор зависит **от контекста,** так как предложение должно встраиваться в текст, и с этой точки зрения эти варианты не всегда взаимозаменяемы. Первый вариант, как мне кажется,  скорее закрывает тему, а второй открывает или продолжает ее.

**Примеры**.

По словам И. Репина, «вдохновение – это награда за каторжный труд».

Как писал Ф. Лассаль, «хотя несомненно, что право должно бы предшествовать силе, но в действительности сила всегда предшествует праву и до тех пор предшествует ему, пока право со своей стороны не наберет достаточно силы, чтобы сломить силу бесправия».

Как писал О. Мандельштам, «отшумит век, уснет культура, переродится народ, отдав свои лучшие силы новому общественному классу, и весь этот поток увлечет за собой эту хрупкую ладью человеческого слова в открытое море грядущего, где нет сочувственного понимания, где унылый комментарий заменяет свежий ветер вражды и сочувствия современников».

Comment: Спасибо большое! Значит, кавычки все же можно ставить таким образом...

Answer (score 3):

Соображения у вас правильные. Корректно оформить вот так:

Как писал А. Пушкин: «...и пальцы просятся к перу, перо к бумаге. Минута – и стихи свободно потекут».

Многоточие ставить нужно (Если цитата приводится не полностью, то пропуски отмечаются многоточием). После "писал А. Пушкин" необходимо ставить двоеточие.

В принципе, в сети есть много шпаргалок на оформление цитат и прямой речи. Например, можете посмотреть на [грамоте.ру](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C) и в [википедии](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-kav1).